# Date Format not appearing correctly

Tags: datetime

```
if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'dd-mm-yyyy'){
         datenow = DateTime.now().format('dd-MM-yyyy');
    }else if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'MM-DD-yyyy'){
         datenow = DateTime.now().format('MM-DD-yyyy');
    }
     else if(invoiceSet[0].Date_Format__c == 'MM/DD/yyyy'){
         datenow = DateTime.now().format('MM/DD/yyyy');
    }
 }
   system.debug('dateeee'+datenoe);
```

in debug for first condition it is showing correctly as 11-12-2012 and in the second condition it is taking in 365 days format & displaying as 12-327-2012.But I want the normal format.How can i do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date format Strings are case sensitive 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

```
DD is day in the year

dd is day in the month
```

So use dd as you have in the first instance.